# How can I pass parameters to the controller?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot

how can I pass parameters to the controller?
html js:

```
window.open("/programs?oper=0&page=1", "_self");
```

Java SpringBoot conntroller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/programs" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ProgramsController(Model model) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    programs cl=new programs();
    int oper=Integer.parseInt(model.getAttribute("oper").toString());
    switch (oper){
        case 0://переход на страницу выбора программ
            int page=Integer.parseInt(model.getAttribute("page").toString());
            int all_pages=0;
            //определяем сколько всего страниц
            all_pages = cl.getSizePages();
            struct_programs mas_result1=null;
            //if(all_pages>0)mas_result1=cl.getPrograms(lang, page);
            break;
    }
    return "programs";
}
```

I am now getting the error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.soft.soft.controllers.Controllers.ProgramsController(Controllers.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]

Comment: The method signature should probably be something like: `public String ProgramsController(@RequestParam("oper") int oper, @RequestParam("page") int page)`.  See @RequestParam for more details.

Comment: Thanks, work!!!